# Different numbers in \label and \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to reference an image in my LaTeX document. In order to do this, I wrote following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{img/2016_02_16_history_site_1.png}
\label{fig:history_site_1}
\caption{Some caption bla-bla}
\end{figure}

See image \ref{fig:history_site_1}.
```

When I compile the document, the caption under the image has number 6.3 (*Fig. 6.3: Some caption bla-bla*), but the reference has number 6.8 (*See image 6.8.*).

How should I modify the code in order for the number to be equal in both caption and the reference?

Comment: Put the label after caption. `\caption` provides the anchor for `\label` and not the figure-environment.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Great! Please post this comment as an answer and I'll accept it.